# Lineary of Sbox in DES

Tags: cryptanalysis, des

I'm not a mathematician, and i would like to understand in the most concise way (if possible) why choosing linear S-Box functions makes the DES algorithm attackable.
Thanks

Comment: Make them identity of the first 4 input?

Comment: Can you write an example ?

Comment: \begin{align}
S:\{0,1\}^6&\to \{0,1\}^4\\
S(a,b,c,d,e,f) &\mapsto (a,b,c,d)
\end{align}

Comment: see this answer, for example https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51017/how-can-one-construct-the-weakest-s-box-ever/51030#51030

Comment: and this one https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63693/s-box-and-its-linearity?rq=1