# AES - Non-linearity hinders differential cryptoanalysis

Tags: aes, differential-analysis

Can you explain me, in simple terms if possible (I'm not a mathematician :( ), why the non-linearity introduced by the AES s-boxes hinder the differential cryptoanalysis ?

Comment: Actually, the first attack is expressing as [linear equations](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63693/18298)

Comment: Doesn't the answer to this question present itself when you look up the terms? Because I'm not sure that we can delve any deeper without involving math.